# Java Bytecode compilation

Tags: java

Using javap I can disassemble a java class into byte code. If I want to run this byte code, or a modified version of it, how do I do it? Please spare me the "don't bother" answers as I am doing this for educational reasons. I've googled and looked at other Stack Overflow questions but couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Do you want to recompile it? You can already run it. Do you mean you want to interpret the mnemonics directly?

Comment: This question doesn't make sense.  A java class /is/ byte code.  javap is typically used to disassemble into human-readable assembly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a java dis-assembler to produce java code you can compile (perhaps with some fixing of the code by hand)

You can then modify the code and re-compile it.